# How to control cpu throttling on android

Tags: android, cpu, throttling

I have heavy duty real time image processing app on android and just got the Samsung Galaxy S3 (9300).

What I observe is that the device is doing heavy throttling on the cpu speed.

Usually my app starts super fast with maximum framerate of a about 30, which then drops down to 9 fps(which is slower than my old Galaxy S 9000) after a couple of minutes. I did some evaluation and when printing out /

sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq

you can see the cpu speed going to from 1.4GHz to 800Mhz.

This behavior is deadly for any game running on android so I was wondering how game developers control this behavior.

Comment: Is your activity in the foreground when this CPU scaling occurs?

Comment: Hey one of my friend is facing similar kind of issue. Can you have a look at this also please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204993/determine-android-cpu-speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out to be a thermal problem. As the app is running the android battery temperature is rising. At 48 degrees android os has throttled down the cpu from 1.4 Ghz to 0.8 Ghz.