# Determine android CPU speed?

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage

One of my friend is into mobile game development. 
Well the issue he faces is like this..
In his game some rooted phone users are able to score very high which is quite impossible unless the the CPU or system clock speed of the android device been slow and that is the case.

Those users use some third party application which makes the device slow and they are able to make absurd high scores.

My question is,
Is there a way to determine that device is running below average CPU speed?
So users cannot make absurd high score?

Any solutions or ideas or thoughts preferred.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875415/how-to-detect-android-cpu-speed & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331538/find-the-processor-speed-of-an-android-device-in-mhz

Comment: AFAIK, the best way is by writing your game code using time-based movement instead of frame-based, so the animation feels the same regardless of CPU speed http://blog.sklambert.com/using-time-based-animation-implement/ I'm still not sure if it's affected by that "CPU hack" as well.

Comment: They are cheating. @akhyar is right, you also need to sync time from the server from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

There is some source library that dose just what you need . Please follow below links . I hope it helps you .

**[CPU Stats](https://github.com/takke/cpustats)** & **[Observe CPU load level](https://github.com/putyta/cpuinfo)**

For you kind information . Please visit here http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html

Comment: How do I use this? I added the class [CpuInfoGrabber][https://github.com/putyta/cpuinfo/blob/master/src/ru/hobud/cpuinfo/CpuMonitorService.java] to my code and add these lines: `CpuInfoGrabber grabber = new CpuInfoGrabber(); grabber.grabCpuInfo();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s\n", grabber.showCurCpuInfo()));` But the output is meagre